# Python how to extract all list elements if they start with the same character set

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

i have to split a list of POS tagged words into sublists according 
to the POS tag used.
My list looks like this:

```
List=[", -> ','", ". -> '!'", ". -> '.'", ". -> '?'", "CC -> 'but'", "CD -> 'hundred'",
      "CD -> 'one'", "DT -> 'the'", "EX -> 'There'","IN -> 'as'", "IN -> 'because'",
      "IN -> 'if'", "IN -> 'in'", "JJ -> 'Sure'", 'MD -> "\'ll"', "MD -> 'ca'",
      "MD -> 'can'", "MD -> 'will'", "MD -> 'would'", "NN -> 'Applause'",
      "NN -> 'anybody'", "NN -> 'doubt'", "NNP -> 'Syria'",
      "NNS -> 'Generals'", "NNS -> 'people'", "NNS -> 'states'",  "PRP -> 'it'",
      "PRP$ -> 'our'",  "RB -> 'there'", "RBR -> 'more'", "RP -> 'out'", "TO -> 'to'",
      "UH -> 'Oh'", "UH -> 'Wow'", "VB -> 'stop'", "VB -> 'want'", "VBD -> 'knew'",
      "VBD -> 'was'", "VBG -> 'allowing'", "VBG -> 'doing'", "VBG -> 'going'",
      "VBN -> 'called'", "VBP -> 'take'", 'VBZ -> "\'s"', "VBZ -> 'is'", 
      "WDT -> 'that'", "WP -> 'what'"]
```

My desired output would be something like

```
[["IN -> 'as'", "IN -> 'because'", "IN -> 'if'", "IN -> 'in'"],["UH -> 'Oh'", "UH -> 'Wow'"]]
```

or even better

```
CC = ['but']
CD = ['hundred', 'one']
```

I searched quite a lot but the only function i could find that at least partly does the work is this:

```
from itertools import groupby
print([list(g) for k, g in groupby(List, key=lambda x: x[0])])
```

I have played around with the value of x, but norhing seems to work very well.

I also thaught about using something like this:

```
RB = []
for item in List:
    if item.startswith('RB'):
        g=re.findall('-> (.*)', item)
        RB.append(g)
```

That should certainly work, but it would be a pain to do this for the about 40 different POS tags. There must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

List = [", -> ','", ". -> '!'", ". -> '.'", ". -> '?'", "CC -> 'but'", "CD -> 'hundred'",
      "CD -> 'one'", "DT -> 'the'", "EX -> 'There'","IN -> 'as'", "IN -> 'because'",
      "IN -> 'if'", "IN -> 'in'", "JJ -> 'Sure'", 'MD -> "\'ll"', "MD -> 'ca'",
      "MD -> 'can'", "MD -> 'will'", "MD -> 'would'", "NN -> 'Applause'",
      "NN -> 'anybody'", "NN -> 'doubt'", "NNP -> 'Syria'",
      "NNS -> 'Generals'", "NNS -> 'people'", "NNS -> 'states'",  "PRP -> 'it'",
      "PRP$ -> 'our'",  "RB -> 'there'", "RBR -> 'more'", "RP -> 'out'", "TO -> 'to'",
      "UH -> 'Oh'", "UH -> 'Wow'", "VB -> 'stop'", "VB -> 'want'", "VBD -> 'knew'",
      "VBD -> 'was'", "VBG -> 'allowing'", "VBG -> 'doing'", "VBG -> 'going'",
      "VBN -> 'called'", "VBP -> 'take'", 'VBZ -> "\'s"', "VBZ -> 'is'", 
      "WDT -> 'that'", "WP -> 'what'"]

data = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in (_.split('->') for _ in List):
  d[key.strip()].add(value.strip().replace("'", '').replace('"', ''))
print(dict(data))
```

This results in:

```
{',': {','}, '.': {'.', '!', '?'}, 'CC': {'but'}, 'CD': {'hundred','one'}, 'DT': {'the'}, 'EX': {'There'}, 'IN': {'in', 'because', 'as', 'if'}, 'JJ': {'Sure'}, 'MD': {'will', 'ca', 'll', 'can', 'would'}, 'NN': {'Applause', 'doubt', 'anybody'}, 'NNP': {'Syria'}, 'NNS': {'Generals', 'states', 'people'}, 'PRP': {'it'}, 'PRP$': {'our'}, 'RB': {'there'}, 'RBR': {'more'}, 'RP': {'out'}, 'TO': {'to'}, 'UH': {'Wow', 'Oh'}, 'VB': {'want', 'stop'}, 'VBD': {'was', 'knew'}, 'VBG': {'going', 'allowing', 'doing'}, 'VBN': {'called'}, 'VBP': {'take'}, 'VBZ': {'s', 'is'}, 'WDT': {'that'}, 'WP': {'what'}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that looks promising. But as i am quite new to this, i have to ask how do i work with these values now? How do i for example look at just the words tagged with VBZ?

Comment: Just use dict indexing `d['VBZ']` >> `{'s', 'is'}`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you clarify that a little more? i´m quite new to programming and more often than not, answers i find on stackoverflow confuse me very much because of their shortness.

Comment: What are you asking?